# Why can't I name a module 'array'?

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, python-module

Given the following directory structure:

```
app/
└── array/
    ├── test/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_array.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── functions.py
```

When I run pytest from the `app` directory, I get the following error:

```
ERROR collecting array/test/test_array.py _______________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/path/to/app/array/test/test_array.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'array.test'; 'array' is not a package
```

Simply renaming the module to `arrays` works, but I don't understand what's wrong with `array`.

Comment: Because array is a built-in type?

Comment: Depending on how you run this, `import array...` may see the builtin `array`, not your `array` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it collides with the [stdlib module of the same name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Comment: Is there a way to keep the name and limit the scope, per se, so that pytest knows what I’m talking about is a local package?

Comment: Somehow depends on you PYTHONPATH set-up, but in your case `import app.array` may help as long as you make app a package. i.e create an empty __init__.py there.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes, you would have to _prepend_ `sys.path`, evict "array" from `sys.modules` if it has already been imported, and then import array again. This is inadvisable, because any _users_ of your package would have the same problem with the stdlib name collision. Just rename the package.

Answer (score 2):

There is already an `array` library in the stdlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html .
So when pytest tries to load from your array module, it probably first search within the `array` in the stdlib, hence the error.

Answer (score -1):

This is because array is a built in Python module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html